# Java Only getting the first value on <input> type hidden on a loop

Tags: java, jsp, for-loop, servlets

I am trying to send a value to my servlet with two inputs, one that is going to have my product name(type hidden) and the other to submit that value;

```
for(Product product : listProducts)
        {
            out.print("Name: " + product.getName());
            %>
            <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="<% out.println(product.getName()); %>">

            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart"/>
            <br>
            <% 

        }
```

The problem is that I only get the first value of the products. And if I do this:

```
for(Product product : listProducts)
        {
            out.print("Name: " + product.getName());
            %>
            <input type="submit" name="flag" value="<% out.println(product.getName()); %>">

            <br>
            <% 

        }
```

it works just fine. So I think is something with the hidden input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try surrounding both `<input>`s with a `<form></form>`.

Comment: thanks mate it worked, I cant' believe this was the error, I feel so dumb

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
for(Product product: listProducts)
            {
                out.print("Name: " + product.getName());
                %>
                <form>
                    <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="<% out.println(product.getName()); 
                     %>">
                     <input type="submit" value="Add to cart"/>
                </form>
                <br>
                <% 
            }
```